# Vatlab Facebook Development kit Internet Explorer Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

I recently purchased Vatlab facebook components and I have a problem with Internet Explorer.

We created a demo application (Asp.NET 4.0) at https://apps.facebook.com/assesmentfinansbank 
It works with firefox, chrome and safari but when we open it with Microsoft Internet Explorer, it continuously redirects the page.

Following code block is the cause of the problem;
AccessToken always returns null and it attemps to redirect the page to authentication page.

```
if (accessToken == null)
{
if (GetRedirectCounter() < 4)
{
IncreaseRedirectCounter();
string authoriseUrl = FvkAuth.GetAuthoriseUrl("email, user_location", FVKConfig.AppUrl);
FvkAuth.RedirectToTop(Response, authoriseUrl);
}
else
{
// too many redirection loops 
Response.Redirect("InfiniteLoop.aspx", false);
}
}
```

I need to fix this problem and require assistance. Anyone faced with this problem and have any sugestion? Thanks

Comment: My guess: _third party cookies_ problem, _again_ …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check did you include following line in your page or master page:

`Response.AppendHeader("P3P", "CP=\"CAO PSA OUR\"");`

it is required to enable third party cookies for iFrame apps on IE. If you 
forgot to include this  asp.net session will not work. Note about this is also 
provided in [FVK documentation](http://vatlab.com/facebook-asp-net-configuration)

Thanks

Comment: Btw I strongly recommend this toolkit. I was working for 3 days on it, and did it in5 minutes with Vatlab :) Also thanks for your fast support.